# Где следует поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

**Он расценил этот жест(,) как намёк(,) и даже разозлился.**

Где следует поставить запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Он расценил этот жест как намёк и даже разозлился.**

1. В предложении союз **как** использован в значении **в качестве** (обороты в этом случае запятыми не выделяются):
   расценил как намек = расценил в качестве намека;
   восприняли как призыв к борьбе = восприняли в качестве призыва к борьбе.
2. **Расценил** и **разозлился** — однородные сказуемые, соединительный союз **и** между ними запятой не требует.

*Предложение оставить машину снаружи он **расценил как намек** на краткость визита **и собирался откланяться**.*
И. Бачинская. Вторая невеста

*...Макс и Юлька только переглядывались с выражением, которое он **расценил как намек на его сумасшествие.***
А. Малышева. Иногда полезно иметь плохую память

Answer (score 1):

Нигде не надо, нет сравнения. (Это об обособлении *как намёк*.)

Сказуемые тут *расценил* и *разозлился*, соединенные одиночным союзом, - знаки не требуются.